# Angular phone pattern validation

Tags: html, angularjs, validation, ng-pattern

is any way to validate phone number in two forms? I would like to validate numbers beginning with "+" and phone without "+". For example, it should pass numbers +238472636 and 193785626.

```
Pattern: /^[\+]\d+$/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **?** for optional characters or blocks:

```
Pattern: /^[\+]?\d+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

The ? quantifier matches the preceding element zero or one time. It is equivalent to {0,1}. ? is a greedy quantifier whose lazy equivalent is ??

so your reg. ex would be like this..

```
/^[\+]?\[0-9]+$/ OR
/^[\+]?\d+$/
```